# Is there a way to fully reload a python module without having references from the previous import?

Tags: python, path, python-import, sys

I have a situation where I need to import a module at runtime.  I don't know the name of the module in advance.  I'm currently doing something to this effect:

```
#Some other code
...

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
module = __import__(moduleName)
reload(module)
sys.path.pop()

#Some inspection stuff
...
```

Following this code, I do some module inspections.

The problem I've encountered is that the inspections are returning old members from the previous time a module with this name was loaded.

**To clarify:**  I'm importing 2 completely different modules from completely different paths, but they happen to have the same name - hence the reload(module) above.

Does anyone know of a way to be able to import a module with the same name (but completely different contents) and have a clean module object to inspect?

Comment: "I'm importing 2 completely different modules from completely different paths, but they happen to have the same name": Done correctly the modules should also have different names. That's the whole point of package namespaces See the [Python docs on import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) for more detail where they show `import package1.moduleName` and `import package2.moduleName` and then there is no ambiguity about which `moduleName` you are referencing.

Comment: @msw The issue is that I don't have control over the names of modules.  They're determined by someone else, and I have to be able to inspect them at run time.  The only information I can really work with is the current working directory and the module name.  There's also no guarantee that there will be an __init__.py present when I'm doing the module inspections, so I can't use "package.moduleName".

Comment: There is code for removing a module at https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-August/048596.html which shows what's involved. Good chance it needs some work. Have not had a chance to try it yet.